# Error reading .msg file downloaded from servlet

Tags: servlets, outlook, outputstream, msg

I have written a servlet which reads the outlook .msg file using [msgparser](http://auxilii.com/msgparser/Page.php?id=18000) and writes the content in ServletOutputStream so that it could be downloaded once the url is hit.

Problem which i am facing is, that file reports an error when i try to open that downloaded file in outlook.

Error says : **Cannot open the file as it may not exists or you may not have permission to access file......**

Even if the file is in right format (.msg), then too there is such error. I am sure I am doing something wrong while parsing. Please suggest. Below is the servlet code :

```
MsgParser msgp = new MsgParser(); 

    Message msg = msgp.parseMsg("D:\\Demo.msg");

    String str1=msg.toString(); 

    byte[] b=str1.getBytes();// here b is byte array 

    //The below code is to open show the pop up so that user can save the msg file.. 

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-outlook"+" ;charset=utf-8"); 

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + "Demo.msg"); 

    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 


    DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(servletOutputStream); 

    if (b!= null) { 
        response.setContentLength(b.length); 

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { 
            dataOutput.writeByte(b[i]); 
        } 

    } 
    if (servletOutputStream != null) { 

        servletOutputStream.flush(); 

        servletOutputStream.close(); 
    } 
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.println(dataOutput);
```

Comment: "Even if the file is in right format (.msg)".  The file extension is not enough to say that the format is right.  Open the file with a text viewer or editor and check it's content.  However it is a permission error, not a format error.

Comment: Yes! I checked the content in notepad++ and content is correct. But still when i double click it to open in outlook, its reporting the error.

Comment: someone please throw some light on this... it would be helpful!

Comment: `MsgParser` just does not have the functionality to return a valid `.msg`-stream. The `toString` method you are using does not what you expect it does: it just returns human-readable text. You have to use the `POIFS`-library to convert the `Message` to a valid `.msg`-data stream.

Comment: I dont see any implementation in POIFS library for this requirement. Please provide some links or documentation in order to achieve so.

Answer (score 0):

If possible set field PR_RTF_IN_SYNC to FALSE:

message.setRtfInSync(false);

I do not use msgparse, but with another library (JMSG) is possible to set this field and that should fix issue "Cannot open the file as it may not exists or you may not have permission to access file"

Comment: JMSG is commercial product and i have to use this at a low level, so was thinking for some open source solution.